# fancybox links inside fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm loading content into a fancybox via ajax, it pops up just fine.

But fancybox links within the ajax content cause it to close and then open.

This did not used to happen before version 2.  It would resize appropriately and load the content right in the open Fancybox without closing it and then reopening it.

Anyone know why it is doing this?

(First link on page):

```
<a class="fancybox-style-1 fancybox.ajax" 
href="[ajax content url]">Link to ajax Content</a>
```

(Second link within Fancybox):

```
<a class="fancybox-style-1 fancybox.ajax" 
href="[another ajax content url]">Link to more ajax Content</a>
```

(Fancybox jQuery in footer of main page:

```
$(".fancybox-style-1").fancybox({
    wrapCSS : 'fancybox-custom',
    padding : 0,
    scrolling: 'no',
    openEffect : 'fade',
    openSpeed  : 150,
    closeEffect : 'fade',
    closeSpeed  : 150,
    closeClick : false,
    topRatio: 0.1,
    helpers : {
        overlay : {
            opacity : 0.4
        },
        title : null
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fading-out -> resizing -> fading-in now items are switched. That is why you see closing and opening.